# Each request ech value response Throughput Shaping Timer

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

So I'm using Concurrency Thread Group with Throughput Shaping Timer.
In TST I have:
one request per second duration 60s
then
two request per second duration 60s
So after all I expect 180 requests but each run I receive different values. Why?
One time 142, another 118.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qOws.png)

[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzUeC.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. You're having some errors in your tests so it worth checking [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries:

   [image]
2. You should not be running your tests in GUI mode, GUI mode is only for tests development and debugging, when it comes to test execution, especially for 1000 virtual users [you should be running your JMeter tests in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)